# Delphi Android: After adding service to app icons and splashscreen images disappears

Tags: android, delphi, service, runtime-error, delphi-10-seattle

I've got a massive error. When I add to project new local service - my main app dosent lunch. This errors I got:

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E2312 Unable to execute '"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe" package -f -M "D:\a\Android\Debug\asas\AndroidManifest.xml" -F "D:\a\Android\Debug\asas\bin\asas-unsigned.apk" -I "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-26\android.jar" -S "D:\a\Android\Debug\asas\res" -A "D:\a\Android\Debug\asas\assets" "D:\a\Android\Debug\asas\library" "D:\a\Android\Debug\asas\classes"' (Error 1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E2312 D:\a\Android\Debug\asas\res\drawable\splash_image_def.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/splash_image').
```

When I go to the Project -> Options -> Application I cant see any of icons or splashscreen images, they disappears. When I add this files manually - app is compiling without errors and starts, but only show black screen for a half second and shutdown. Without adding to project a service everything works very well, app starts normally. I tried reinstall Rad Studio - and nothing changes... In about month ago I created app with service and Delphi works fine. Im using Delphi 10 Seattle.

I dont know what I must do... my project stuck. Please, help me...

Comment: Have you watched this video? [Android Services for Background Execution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_MLkBcNvSM)

Comment: Yes. I know how to create service, etc. I just have an error with Delphi. Emmm... maybe someone know how to repair it? Or something like that..

Comment: Did you check SDK Manager for any error or warning. check SDK,NDK and Java tabs. also did you use a TMapView?

Comment: Yea, I check. Everything was alright. My thing was to activate at Project Menager: main app with the double click... So simply, so easy... After then my application runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Project Menager (upper right corner). To compile and run application correctly you must double click at main app name. When you did it, name of main app is bold. Then - everything is working very well. Thats all.

Comment: In the video I mentioned above, Jim McKeeth makes extensive use of the Project Manager.